# Entity Framework. Selecionar apenas 1 em uma lista no Include?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando pegar apenas um 1 registro das listas Telefones e Emails.

```
var lista = Db.Oportunidades
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Proprietario)
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Contatos.Select(c => c.Telefones))
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Contatos.Select(c => c.Emails))
    .Include(x => x.Estado)
    .Include(x => x.Motivo)
    .Include(x => x.Tipo);
```

Já tentei usar `First()`, `Sigle()`, `Take(1)` que geram o erro abaixo.

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Nome do parâmetro: path

Alguma dica?

Comment: Acredito que esse link possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676029/the-include-path-expression-must-refer-to-a-navigation-property-defined-on-the-t

Comment: Provavelmente você terá de usar algo assim: var lista = Db.Oportunidades
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Proprietario)
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Contatos)
    .Include(x => x.Estado)
    .Include(x => x.Motivo)
    .Include(x => x.Tipo)
 .Select(c => new {
  Telefone = x.Conta.Contatos.Select(c => c.Telefones).First(),
  Email = x.Conta.Contatos.Select(c => c.Emails).First(),
  }).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É impossível. A função **`Include`** não dá suporte a estes tipos de operações.

Você pode usar o `Select` e retornar um tipo anônimo contendo o registro principal, telefone e email.

Exemplo:

```
var lista = Db.Oportunidades
    .Include(x => x.Conta.Proprietario)
    .Include(x => x.Estado)
    .Include(x => x.Motivo)
    .Include(x => x.Tipo)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Registro = x,
        Telefone = x.Conta.Contatos.Telefones.FirstOrDefault(),
        Email = x.Conta.Contatos.Emails.FirstOrDefault(),
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado. Estava tentando não fazer dessa forma pois vou ter q mudar o retorno, q hoje já espera um list de oportunidades, e consequentemente os objetos que esperam ele. Vlw